# Installing UltraNav Driver increases boot up time

Tags: windows-7, drivers, thinkpad

I'm using a [Thinkpad W520](http://www.lenovo.com/products/us/laptop/thinkpad/w-series/w520/) with Windows 7 and a [Crucial M4 256GB SSD](http://www.crucial.com/store/listmodule/SSD/~262144~/list.html) (not sure if this is also part of the cause of the problem). Normally the boot up time is between 20 to 25 seconds. However, when I update the UltraNav driver to the latest version, the boot up time is significantly increased to around 50 seconds. And when I use Device Manager to roll back the version of the UltraNav driver to PS/2 Compatible Mouse, the boot up time is normal again.

My question is: has anyone else also observed this incompatibility issue between UltraNav with (Windows 7 or SSD)? Is there a solution to this problem?

Comment: Maybe that's why my T500 boot up time increased? Well, I can wait. 1 or 2 minutes... :) Ps.: I'm using a simple 7200RPM laptop HDD. But yes, after the security updates, Windows was really fast. It booted up in a blink. After installing the Lenovo stuff, the boot got much longer.

Comment: @Shiki: You can try uninstall that UltraNav driver to see if boot up time is shorter...

Comment: Will do that once I decide to reboot. Having an HDD makes me hate rebooting and stuff. :)

Comment: I would post this issue on the Lenovo forums...http://forums.lenovo.com/t5/W-Series-ThinkPad-Laptops/bd-p/W_ThinkPads

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it does, in my case windows 7 waits for an additional 10 seconds or so with a "Please Wait" message before the logon screen "Ctrl+Alt+Del" pops up on windows 7.

Uninstalled it no more wait. However obviously the 2 finger scroll etc features are no longer usable.

I have a 160Gig intel ssd.